# Question on limit of Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I'm trying to follow the following calculation of the definite integral using a limit of Riemann Sums.  I have a question on the reasoning for a step in derivation of the limit which I will detail.

The original post is [here](https://www.ck12.org/book/ck-12-calculus-concepts/section/5.5/).

$$\int_0^3 x^3 dx = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x^*_i) \Delta x$$

$$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)\left(\frac 3n\right)$$

$$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 3 n\right) \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)^3$$

$$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 3 n\right)^4 \sum_{i=1}^n i^3$$

My first question is how is $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ multiplied to both sides when the RHS is unknown. Is the RHS assumed to be 1?

$$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 3 n\right)^4 \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$

My second question is how are the next two equations derived from the prior?

$$= \left(\frac {3^4} 4\right) \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 1 {n^4}\right) \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$

$$= \left(\frac {3^4} 4\right) \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^2$$

$$= \frac {3^4} 4$$

Comment: $= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac 3 n)^4 (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$ should be $= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac 3 n)^4 (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2\color{red};\; \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac 3 n)^4 (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$ should be

$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac 3 n)^4 (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$ makes use of $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$.

(Also, I saw *Riemann* spelled incorrectly there.)

**Addendum to answer additional question posted as comment on this question:**

It should be

$$= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 3 n\right)^4 \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac {3^4} 4\right) \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 1 {n^4}\right) \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{\color{red}1}\right)^2,$$

because $$\left(\dfrac3n\right)^4 \left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2=3^4\left(\dfrac1n\right)^4\dfrac1{2^2}(n(n+1))^2 .$$

Finally,

$$\left(\dfrac1n\right)^4(n(n+1))^2=\dfrac{n^2}{n^4}(n+1)^2=\dfrac1{n^2}(n+1)^2=\left(\dfrac{n+1}n\right)^2=\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^2.$$

Comment: I'm not sure where $(\frac {3^4} {4})$ came from

Comment: @Nick:  I addended my answer to address that.  You should have typed $1$ where you typed $2$.  Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: That helped.  I'm still confused how they arrived at this from the prior equation $$= \left(\frac {3^4} 4\right) \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^2$$

Comment: Okay, I added some explanation for that